# PHP 5.6 instalado e phpinfo mostra 5.5

Tags: php

Estou com um mac os x yosemite e instalei o php até mesmo quando rodo o comando php -v ele me traz o php 5.6 instalado, o mesmo está no caminho /usr/local/Cellar/php56/5.6.5/bin/php que eu adicionei no path do sistema nano ~/.bash_profile mas simplesmente minhas ides monstrão o php 5.5 sendo que o path dentro da IDE está /usr/local/Cellar/php56/5.6.5/bin/php é estranho por que isso acontece?

Comment: Tenta parar totalmente Apache e re-iniciar.

Comment: já fiz isso mas não deu certo.

Comment: isso pode ajudar: http://getgrav.org/blog/mac-os-x-apache-setup-multiple-php-versions

Comment: Você m,encionou sobre ter adicionado o path dentro da "IDE".. ok, mas não modificou o httpd.conf do Apache?

Comment: resolvido instalei com o brew install php5 depois exportei para o path no ~/bash_profile